# Protecting files from a direct HTTP request

Tags: php, security, httprequest

Let's say you have a bunch of documents hosted on your webserver but you don't want them to be retrieved by a direct HTTP request, since those files are confidential. We started to encrypt the filename, but we want it to take 1 step further, so what about placing those files outside the /public_html folder and have PHP retrieve the requested file from the folder outside the /public_html?

I'm trying to test this but my little script is retrieving me a 0kb .pdf file with the wrong filename:

```
<?php 

$file = '/home/clientaccount/secretfiles/file.pdf'; 
if(!file_exists($file)){
    die('Error: File not found.');
}
else
{
    // Set headers
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
} ?>
```

Comment: What server are you using?  an `.htaccess` file might be more appropriate for you.

Comment: do you echo the content of the file after this?  or is that the whole script?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the details: We are using Apache. As for the .htaccess, can you ellaborate your thought? As for echoing the content, that is the entire script, as we don't mean to echo the file, but instead force the file to be downloaded.

Comment: you can't ,if the file outside public_html , most likely the user has no permission to connect to any file there. you have to stream the content using your headers but echoing the content of the file so that user can receive it.

Comment: I believe the "stream" is the keyword here, since it must drain the content from A to B. I will try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code work properly, I had to add a comand to make php read the file and output it:

```
<?php 

$file = '/tmp/file.pdf'; 
if(!file_exists($file)){
    die('Error: File not found: '.$file);
}
else
{

    // Set headers
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    readfile($file);
} 

?>
```

Otherwise I couldn't read the file after download.

As Hans Kuit said, it would be better to remove the path from the file name.

Comment: Yep, just tried this and it worked, and filename had to be renamed to a simple string. Thank you all for your input, bit by bit, with all contributions this is pretty much the output. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

The variable $file is just a string. The header which reaches your visitor tells:

> Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename=/home/clientaccount/secretfiles/file.pdf

This is not a folder a visitor could reach.

Comment: You have to make sure that Apache has access like @user1498339 mentioned.. Also make sure that your header contains the filename only, not the entire path/to/the/file.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You have to many right parenthesis in the if, should be:

```
if(!file_exists($file)){
```

This is probably the cause of the server error and your code should work, provided the user running the server has access to the external location.

Comment: Ok, someone shoot me in the foot here... A small typo was throwing the 500 error. The question has been updated. Thank you user1498339

Comment: I tried your code and it works, but I had to move the file from my home directory to /tmp/, because the apache user couldn't access the file in my home directory.

Comment: Sorry, it asked to download the file but I couldn't read it (I had not check this part).